# Problem at using Bool Tool add on

Tags: modifiers, add-on, tools

I have a strange problem at using Bool Tool add-on. I exactly do what I should but it doesn't work. How do I go about this issue?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: maybe take a look at your modifier, try Fast or Exact, make sure that Intersect is selected...

Comment: i didn't use any modifiers! i only added Bool Tool add on like him and did exactly what have he done, this is his video: https://youtu.be/b8fWhClnSNw

Comment: I think that the Bool Tool uses the Boolean modifier fonctions, if you use the Brush Boolean function you'll see that it creates and keeps the Boolean modifier, while Auto Boolean will directly apply the boolean. Maybe try Brush Boolean, which keeps the modifier, and try the other solver. Also, your objects don't seem to be exactly the same as in the video, so different topologies may interact differently and give bad result, you need to find out how to solve it, either with the modifier tweaking, or manually

Comment: look, i'm so pretty sure that it doesn't need modifier, cuz i tried this again and i saw that it worked, but it worked when the objects were small, so i made them bigger and tried again and i saw that it didn't work, and i tried again with small ones and i saw that it doesn't work anymore!!! it's impossible!!!!! ik that my laptop has a little bugs sometimes, but i don't think about this one

Comment: booleans (whether it is bool tool or modifier, they will work the same way) don't always work correctly, it depends on the topology of the object and of the boolean object, what you can do though is share your file so that we can try: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: a'ight so u mean that i share my blend file so that u can try to solve the problem right? ok i'll do that soon, for now i need to go to somewhere, after that i'll upload it and if u want to have a better contact to me, here is my Gmail: pouriajavadi0@gmail.com

Comment: Edit your initial question and put the link to your file  ;)

Comment: uhhh....look bro, the site is banned in where i am, i uploaded it on media fire: https://www.mediafire.com/file/a20y3mupffehcr2/Bool+Tool+Test.rar/file

Comment: is it what you're trying to do? https://zupimages.net/up/21/29/m1ee.jpg it seems to work fine, but it will apply your Array modifiers, unless you use a Boolean modifier (in that case remember that you need to make the triangle display > wire otherwise you won't see what's happening inside)

Comment: ye that's what i wanted, but i rlly don't wanna use modifier for the bool cuz it'll make my job a little more difficult(i mean like its rendering)but ok i'll try that too and if i had any prob i'll tell u again, and ummm....can u talk to me with email? cuz i don't get notification from this site and since i can save my helpful mails so it'll help me too.

Comment: actually Bool Tool uses the Boolean modifier  ;)

Comment: a'ight :3‌‌ so ok i'll use mofier too

Answer (score 0):

I think I found my answer. Sometimes this method works without modifier, but most of the times not. It's better to use it with modifier, and if we want to render it in Eevee, we can give to the shape a transparent material (I mean like that triangle), so that we can also render it as well with Eevee engine.